# Where with lambda in haskell

Tags: haskell, syntax, where-clause, let

I am reading the 2nd edition of the (great) book from Graham Hutton ["Progamming in Haskell"](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~pszgmh/pih.html) (Cambridge Press).

Reading the State Monad section, I stumbled on a small task that I gave myself.

How could you rewrite the following using `where` instead of `let`?

```
type State = Int
newtype ST a = S (State -> (a, State))

instance Functor ST where
    -- fmap :: (a -> b) -> ST a  -> ST b
    fmap g st = S (\state -> let (x, s') = app st state in (g x, s'))
```

I tried variations around this code but it doesn't work:

```
instance Functor ST where
   -- fmap :: (a -> b) -> ST a  -> ST b
   fmap g st = S (\state -> (g x, newstate))
              where (x, newstate) = app st state
```

I know it's not useful per se, but I would like to know if and how it is possible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`let BINDINGS in EXPRESSION` is an expression and can be used anywhere an expression is allowed.

`where` only attaches to declarations, not expressions. `\state -> ...` is not a declaration, so you can't attach `where` to it. You can't attach it to an outer declaration either because then `state` won't be in scope.

Possible solution:

```
instance Functor ST where
    fmap g st = S f
        where
        f state = (g x, s')
            where (x, s') = app st state
```

Instead of an anonymous function `\state -> ...` we have a local declaration `f state = ...`, to which we can attach a `where` clause that has access to `state`.